# HEATMAP AND PAIRGRID

Tags: concatenation, heatmap, pairplot

its about covid 19 and I want to find the factor that causes death due to covid 19 and the correlation between the factors. Factors such as death number, number of vaccination, Daily hospital occupancy, new cases. I want a correlation between the different factors. also I want the correlation within the factors (box plot). It give me error when I try pair grid and heat map.

It's a future error. """"" /var/folders/4_/hvm3glsx0dgfrz2xvs7jf4340000gn/T/ipykernel_3898/1310114520.py:1: FutureWarning:
The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning.
/var/folders/4_/hvm3glsx0dgfrz2xvs7jf4340000gn/T/ipykernel_3898/1310114520.py:2: FutureWarning:
The default value of numeric_only in DataFrame.corr is deprecated. In a future version, it will default to False. Select only valid columns or specify the value of numeric_only to silence this warning. """"
and they printed empty grids

I am trying to find the co-relation of the factors concurrently. Hoping to use pair grid and heat map in pandas but it return error. I used dataframe before making into pair grid and heat map thus, hoping to use data frames and then pair grid and heat map :( please help.
Attached is my sample data.
expecting to have heat map and pairgrid to find the relationships between the factors using dataframes
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17MGYY26eisyjRpL4b_P_o-rGDAHP-K5on5sD9BFZJ6Y/edit?usp=sharing)

I suspect that when I try to concatenate the datas from different data source, it return NaN.

Thus, I would like to ask if there is anywhere I could concatenate data from different data frames into one data frame without distorting the data.

Hope to hear from you soon
Thank You.